How to pass secrets to cloud run job
How can i pass secrets to cloud rub job using containerOverrides property i can not find any documentation about this.
I am passing env variables like this but this is visible in cloud run jobs UI and i dont want my secrets leaked.
    const [runOperation] = await jobsClient.runJob({
      name: jobPath,
      overrides: {
        containerOverrides: [
          {
            args: jobArguments,
            env: [
              {
                name: "FIRESTORE_DATABASE_URL",
                value: firestoreDatabaseUrl.value(),
              },
            ],
            
          },
        ],
      },
    });

EDIT:
Found this in the source code is there any examples on how to use it.
  interface IEnvVarSource {

                    /** EnvVarSource secretKeyRef */
                    secretKeyRef?: (google.cloud.run.v2.ISecretKeySelector|null);
                }


I was able to figure it out without documentation like everything in GCP -.-
PLS GOOGLE START WRITING DOCUMENTATION!

    const [runOperation] = await jobsClient.runJob({
      name: jobPath,
      overrides: {
        containerOverrides: [
          {
            env: [
              {
                name: "ELASTIC_ENTERPRISE_AUTH_TOKEN",
                valueSource: {
                  secretKeyRef: {
                    secret: "ELASTIC_ENTERPRISE_AUTH_TOKEN",
                    version: "latest",
                  },
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    });


Store them in GitHub secrets/Azure vault or whatever platform you’re using

There must be native way for google cloud to do it
